# Detecting touch on gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to detect a touch on a GameObject  without sucess. My code copied from some examples is:

```cs
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("Mouse Clicked!!");
        Vector3 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 worldPoint2D = new Vector2(worldPoint.x, worldPoint.y);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(worldPoint2D, Vector2.zero);
        Debug.Log(hit.collider);

    }
}
```

The output is always null :(

The game object is not moving and is a simple Cube with a box colider.

Comment: you object is moving?

Comment: I'm surprised you were able to Raycast2D with a Vector3.  Also, Vector2.zero is (0,0,0). Is that really the **direction** you want to cast?  Not really a direction. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html

Comment: The object is not moving

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your `Vector3 worldPoint` into `Vector2`. So like this:

```
Vector3 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
Vector2 worldPoint2D = new Vector2(worldPoint.x, worldPoint.y);
```

and then use `worldPoint2D` in the raycast.

Comment: You may also try adding the third parameter in the raycast function and set it to a high number. This parameter indicates the distance, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself...I was not be able to resolve the question using Phisycs2D.Raycast method but Phisics.Raycast did the work:

```cs
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.collider);
        }
    }
}
```